# Abstract Functors in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to write an abstract base class

```
class func_double_double_t : public unary_function<double, double>
{
    virtual double operator()(double x) = 0;
};
```

and specialize it for several different types

```
class func_pow_t : public func_double_double_t
{
 public:
    func_pow_t(double exponent) : exponent_(exponent) {};
    virtual double operator()(double x) { return pow(x, exponent_); };
}

class func_exp_t : public func_double_double_t
...
```

and pass these to a function when necessary:

```
double make_some_calculation(double num, func_double_double_t f)
{
     return f(x);
}
```

But I can't define an object of type `func_double_double_t` because it's abstract. I can pass a pointer to the function, but using `f` like `f->operator()(num)` seems against the spirit of operator overloading in the first place. (`(*f)(num)` is better, but still.)

Is there way to make operator overloading and such abstraction play nicely together?

Comment: Your code is a rather misguided mix of "classic" OOP run-time polymorphism and template compile-time polymorphism. You need to decide which one you are trying to use first and then follow that decision. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: AndreyT, I tend to derive all classes using having `operator()` from `unary_function` or `binary_function`. I could skip that, this question is about runtime polymorphism. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass a reference into your function:

```
double make_some_calculation(double num, func_double_double_t& f)
{
    return f(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can get there by passing the function as a reference, the C++11 standard has these functor types built in:

```
double make_some_calculation(double d, std::function< double(double) > f) {
   return f(d);
}


...
auto add_2=std::bind( std::plus(), 2.0 );
double result=make_some_calculation(1.1, add_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the obvious answer would be to pass a reference, so you just use: `f(num)`, about like usual.

Unless you need to be able to use different function objects at run-time (e.g., have an array of functors of different types, and invoke them all in a loop) you might consider making the function to be invoked a template parameter instead:

```
template <class F>
double do_some_calculation(double num) { 
    return f(num);
}
```

If the function to be used is known at compile time, this will generally be preferred.

Comment: Adding templates and using typedefs might be preferable, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of basic concepts that you might want to revisit. First the direct answer to your question is that you should pass a *reference*, which allows for the nice syntax and passing different derived instances.

Beyond that, if you want runtime polymorphic behavior then your `operator()` should be virtual in the base class (maybe left out while copying to the question? --i.e. without `virtual` the *pure-specifier* `=0` is ill formed)

Comment: For the basic concepts you may be right, thank you. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @EmreSahin: Why are you using virtual inheritance?

Comment: There are different kinds of objects that I don't exactly know beforehand. These are different features of word images scanned from paper. There are also comparators that run to decide whether these features are similar enough or not. The features mostly use templates, to achieve a concrete interface. For the comparators I'm using runtime polymorphism, since they are simpler and more likely to be replaced with one another. Does this explain?

Comment: @EmreSahin: That explains the use of `virtual` for the methods, but not the `virtual` in the inheritance. You might want to revisit that concept also :) Virtual inheritance only makes sense when your type hierarchy is not a proper tree (i.e. one type directly or indirectly inherits from a base multiple times. Think `struct A {}; struct B : virtual A {}; struct C : virtual A {}; struct D : B, C {}`, where `D` inherits indirectly from `A` twice, through both `B` and `C`, but you only want one instance of `A` in your final object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement it through run-time polymorphism, you need the following

1. The base class function shall be declared `virtual` (where is it?)

   ```
   class func_double_double_t : public unary_function<double, double>
   {
       virtual double operator()(double x) = 0;
   };
   ```
2. The derived classes do not need `virtual` when inheriting from base class (why did you put it there?)

   ```
   class func_pow_t : public func_double_double_t {
     ...
   ```
3. The calling function should receive the object by pointer or reference

   ```
   double make_some_calculation(double num, func_double_double_t& f)
   {
     return f(x);
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   double make_some_calculation(double num, func_double_double_t* f)
   {
     return (*f)(x);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. i'd like to select more than one answer.